Transfer selective data from master table to a dashboard (don't want pivots)
Say I have a table A2:H8 (SourceTable) in my source sheet, as shown in my screenshot_1.
I am trying to create a dynamically updatable table on a separate sheet (named 'Dashboard'). By 'dynamically updatable table,' I mean the one that should expand (more rows) or contract (fewer rows) automatically, based on the number of rows with the value = "report" in the SourceTable.
So if I have 4 rows with the value "report" in H column of my Source Table, the dynamically updatable table on a Dashboard sheet should also have 4 rows. If I switch one value from "hide" to "report" in H column of my SourceTable, the dynamically updatable table on a Dashboard sheet should also now have 5 rows with the respective data.
I managed to do this with the FILTER formula
=FILTER(SourceTable,SourceTable[Status]="report") 

See screenshot_2.
BUT!!!
For the added row, I don't want to copy values from all columns in SourceTable. Say I just need Column 1, Column 6, and Column 7. How do I do that?
This is what I ultimately want (see screenshot_3)
Source Table:



Column 1
Column 2
Column 3
Column 4
Column 5
Column 6
Column 7
Column 8




name 1
value 2.1
value 3.1
value 4.1
value 5.1
value 6.1
value 7.1
hide


name 2
value 2.2
value 3.2
value 4.2
value 5.2
value 6.2
value 7.2
hide


name 3
value 2.3
value 3.3
value 4.3
value 5.3
value 6.3
value 7.3
hide


name 4
value 2.4
value 3.4
value 4.4
value 5.4
value 6.4
value 7.4
report


name 5
value 2.5
value 3.5
value 4.5
value 5.5
value 6.5
value 7.5
report


name 6
value 2.6
value 3.6
value 4.6
value 5.6
value 6.6
value 7.6
report


name 7
value 2.7
value 3.7
value 4.7
value 5.7
value 6.7
value 7.7
report




Dashboard (what I got now):



Column 1
Column 2
Column 3
Column 4
Column 5
Column 6
Column 7
Column 8




name 4
value 2.4
value 3.4
value 4.4
value 5.4
value 6.4
value 7.4
report


name 5
value 2.5
value 3.5
value 4.5
value 5.5
value 6.5
value 7.5
report


name 6
value 2.6
value 3.6
value 4.6
value 5.6
value 6.6
value 7.6
report


name 7
value 2.7
value 3.7
value 4.7
value 5.7
value 6.7
value 7.7
report




Dashboard (What I want):



Column 1
Column 6
Column 7




name 4
value 6.4
value 7.4


name 5
value 6.5
value 7.5


name 6
value 6.6
value 7.6


name 7
value 6.7
value 7.7





=FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(SourceTable,1,6,7),SourceTable[Status]="report")?

In additions to @ScottCraner Sir's answer, when you are doing it dynamic, make it more dynamic by using the column headers, like this way. =CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(SourceTable,SourceTable[Status]="report"),XMATCH(A2:C2,SourceTable[#Headers])) so you dont have to hardcode the column index
